# User Workflow email alert - VF Email template unable to access {!Community_Url}

Tags: apex, community

There are questions on the topic of 'How to disable OOTB welcome email' on communities and I am unable to find answers on any of them.

I have created a User workflow email alert and used a VF email template using the variable '{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}'. This value is coming as blank. I do not quite understand how this variable might know the context of the community if the user has access to many communities.

What merge fields should I use in 'RelatedType' on the vf email template? how should I get to use this variable {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}?